# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Value cannot be null. Help needed

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, winium

When trying to invoke winium driver for my file upload from local into web, it's showing below error,

**Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Value cannot be null.**

Further digging got to know that getSecurityManager is returning null and that's causing the issue.

Any help???

**My code:**

```
public static void WiniumFileUpload() throws MalformedURLException
    {
        System.out.println("Step-1");
        DesktopOptions options=new DesktopOptions();
        System.out.println("Step-2"); 
        WiniumDriver Win=new WiniumDriver(new URL("http://localhost:9999"),options);
        System.out.println("Step-3");
}
```

It's executing till Step-2.

**Error:**

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
>   Value cannot be null. Parameter name: executableFilePath (WARNING: The
>   server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or
>   timeout: 58 milliseconds Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision:
>   '41bccdd10cf2c0560f637404c2d96164b67d9d67', time: '2015-10-09
>   13:08:06' System info: host: 'SPICITY948', ip: '11.48.179.107',
>   os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1',
>   java.version: '1.8.0_171' Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.winium.WiniumDriver

Comment: *Further digging got to know that getSecurityManager is returning null* Can you show where do you use `getSecurityManager` and what is this method doing?